# Webpack and generators

Tags: webpack, babeljs

It seems `webpack` needs [regenerator-runtime](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regenerator-runtime) to bundle `AsyncFunction` and generators (and it seems not even enough..). Since both are widely supported by browsers. I don't want to transpile it, is there a way to bundle with webpack without using babel for those?